# How to Combine two classification model in matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, classification, face-detection, matlab-cvst

I am trying to detect the faces using the Matlab built-in viola jones face detection. Is there anyway that I can combine two classification models like "FrontalFaceCART" and "ProfileFace" into one in order to get a better result?

Thank you.

Comment: Usually classification models output some sort of probability measure that determine how likely that input belongs to the class they are trying to differentiate themselves from.  Simply use an unseen input that wasn't part of the training into both models and assign the class of the input to be whichever one gave you the highest *a posteriori* probability.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine models. That's a non-sense in any classification task since every classifier is different (works differently, i.e. different algorithm behind it, and maybe is also trained differently).

According to the classification model(s) help (which can be found [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetector-class.html#bs_hhwg-4)), your two classifiers work as follows:

- FrontalFaceCART is a model composed of weak classifiers, based on classification and regression tree analysis
- ProfileFace is composed of weak classifiers, based on a decision stump

More infos can be found in the link provided but you can easily see that their inner behaviour is rather different, so you can't mix them or combine them.
It's like (in Machine Learning) mixing a Support Vector Machine with a K-Nearest Neighbour: the first one uses separating hyperplanes whereas the latter is simply based on distance(s).

You can, however, train several models in parallel (e.g. independently) and choose the model that better suits you (e.g. smaller error rate/higher accuracy): so you basically create as many different classifiers as you like, give them the same training set, evaluate each accuracy (and/or other parameters) and choose the best model.

Comment: But how about if i run two separate vision.CascadeObjectDetector objects with FrontalFaceCART and ProfileFace and then run each one on my image?is that okay? Actually I have done something similar. I have run the image through the both models and got two sets of bounding boxes for each. Then concatenate them together into a single matrix in order to get one result out of them. But there is only one problem which is overlapping of bounding boxes? any idea how to get rid of them?

Comment: So you're basically doing what I was suggesting (running models in parallel), but instead of picking the best result, you're trying to pick some sort of tradeoff between them. So you're combining the *results* and not the *models*. That makes more sense.

Comment: The overlapping boxes problem is something related to the fact that you're using outputs from both models. You can't avoid it, but of course you can discard a box or join boxes together. That's actually the *combination phase* of your results, and I reckon you must do it manually. Try googling "overlapping rectangles matlab" or something like that, it is a very studied problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a hierarchical classifier. So in a first step you use the frontal face classifier (assuming that most pictures are frontal faces). If the classifier fails, you try with the profile classifier.

I did that with a dataset of faces and it improved my overall classification accuracy. Furthermore, if you have some a priori information, you can use it. In my case the faces were usually in the middle up part of the picture.

To further improve your performance, without using the two classifiers in MATLAB you are using, you would need to change your technique (and probably your programming language). This is the best method so far: [Facenet](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832).